# How to select multiple cells from table in horizontal order only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select multiple cells from the HTML table in Horizontal order only with the help of javascript/jquery, how can I do that?
The Code Am referring is as bellow,i have a simple HTML table with `<tr></tr>` and `<td></td>`

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      if ($('.table').length) {
          var $td = $('.table').find('td');
          var isMouseDown = false;
          var isHighlighted;

          $td.mousedown(function () {
              isMouseDown = true;
              $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
              isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
              return false;
          }).mouseenter(function () {
              if (isMouseDown) {
                  $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
              }
          }).mouseup(function () {
              if (isMouseDown) {
                  $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
              }
          }).on("selectstart", function () {
              return false;
          });

          $(document).mouseup(function () {
              isMouseDown = false;
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: what are you working on now?where are you stuck at?share all relevant information and codes on OP

Comment: show us what you've done!

Comment: There is not enough information but it is quite easy, just select childrens of <tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need?

---

**EXPLAINS :**

- I am create two event listener for entire body elements using <kbd>mousedown</kbd> and <kbd>mouseup</kbd> to watching mouse button actions while acting on entire body elements. And for each first <kbd>mousedown</kbd> event I've remove all <kbd>.highlight</kbd> class.
- And when mouse entering <kbd>td</kbd> on <kbd>table</kbd> I am watching the hover event. So we can add a new <kbd>.highlight</kbd> class into the <kbd>td</kbd> when the pointer entering the <kbd>td</kbd> object.

---

**UPDATE :**

- Adding logic for selecting the same row only.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var lastTr = -1;
  
  $('body').mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $('td').removeClass('highlight');
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
  });

  $("table td").hover(function(){
    var ctr = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    lastTr = lastTr === -1 ? ctr : lastTr;
    
    if (isMouseDown)
      if (lastTr !== ctr)
        $('td').removeClass('highlight');
      else
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    
    lastTr = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  });

  $("table td").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks,it's working finely here i have one more issue is that suppose  firstly i dragged(hover) mouse on 4 cells and still mouse is not released and i hoverd back from 2 cells then now it should show only two cells selected,is  it possible?

Comment: Sure is possible... but i think it will be better if you create a new question... since, its out of scope from your first question...